# How do I add a time-stamped note to the LOGBOOK drawer

Tags: org-mode, logging

According to the [documentation of Drawers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Drawers.html), I should be able to add a time-stamped note to the LOGBOOK drawer using the command `C-c C-z`.

However, when I try to do this with my cursor on a TODO task, a note with timestamp is added *above* the task and without a LOGBOOK drawer:

```
- Note taken on [2020-03-14 Sat 11:50] \\
  Started working on nice task
* TODO Nice task
```

When I do the same thing *under* a task, I get the following result, still without a LOGBOOK drawer:

```
* TODO Hard task
  - Note taken on [2020-03-14 Sat 11:51] \\
    Man, this task is very hard. I don't know if I can do it...
```

Finally, when I manually add a LOGBOOK drawer myself and navigate the cursor *into* the LOGBOOK drawer area, the note gets added *above* the drawer:

```
* TODO Clock hours
  - Note taken on [2020-03-14 Sat 11:52] \\
    Add a note to the logbook of this task to see if it works...
:LOGBOOK:

:END:
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the aforementioned documentation wrong? The only thing I want to do is add notes with a timestamp to a task to be able to log my progress and thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set or customize the variable `org-log-into-drawer` to `t`.<sup>*</sup> The doc string of the variable (`C-h v org-log-into-drawer RET`) states:

> Non-nil means insert state change notes and time stamps into a drawer.
>   When nil, state changes notes will be inserted after the headline and
>   any scheduling and clock lines, but not inside a drawer.

If you want to make this file specific, you can add a line like this to the top of your file (and then either do `C-c C-c` on that line or save the buffer and revert it from the file on disk, so that Org mode will get reinitialized):

```
#+STARTUP: logdrawer
```

<sup>*<sub>You can do this by adding `(setq org-log-into-drawer t)` to your emacs configuration file.</sub></sup>